# How to get all the HTTP Objects

Tags: http, browser, webkit, scrapy, wget

Hi everyone so here is the question: I want to get all the objects of website not the ones being showed in the browser but the ones we actually issued http requests for 
for example I want to get all the objects for which I issued http get request

Comment: How come you don't know for what objects you issued HTTP GET requests?

Comment: I know but I want to automate this process. Like I just isssue a request for google.com and it automatically saves all the objects which my browser would be requesting (in the same way if i visit google.com from my browser). Somehow I am not able to get all the objects my browser actually requested because of scrapbook manipulation of the data

Comment: So I was looking for something that behaves in the same way as web browser but dun change the data

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example for your scenario? (e.g. how to you make a request and how you try (and fail) to query the information you want?)